# Grid of Plots in Julia

Tags: plot, grid-layout, julia, gadfly

How can I make a grid of plots in Julia using Gadfly?

Lets say I have an array of plots `p` as an example

```
p=[plot(y=[1:10],x=[1:10]),plot(y=[1:10],x=[1:10]),plot(y=[1:10],x=[1:10])]
```

I want to put this in a 2x2 grid (note 3x1 and 1x3 are easy using `vstack` and `hstack`)

I see a `gridstack` function in the Compose package. This takes a matrix of canvases. So I could use this function if there was some way of making an 'empty' plot:

```
gridstack( reshape([[render(p[i]) for i in 1:3], render( ...empty plot...)],2,2))
```

Comment: instead of render(...empty...) a simple canvas() might just be enough, but I can't test it right now.

Comment: yes, you are right using canvas() works just fine to make a blank canvas! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using canvas() to create an empty default canvas that can be used as placeholder should be the right way to do it.

```
gridstack( reshape([[render(p[i]) for I in 1:3], canvas()],2,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it should be like this:

```
cs = reshape([Context[render(pl[i]) for i in 1:numrows],context()], iceil(numrows/2),2);
p = gridstack(cs)
```